# How to bind a keypress to a button in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, robotics

My Senior Project involves a robot I can control over wifi. I am using a Raspberry Pi and a Tkinter window to send commands to the robot. I have the rough draft of my Tkinter window, but I am wondering if there is a way to bind the button press to the arrow keys. That way I can control the robot by using my arrow keys rather than clicking on each button. Here is my code, what would I have to add?

Code:

```
from Tkinter import *


message = ""

class App:

    def __init__(self, master):

        frame=Frame(master)
        frame.grid()

        status = Label(master, text=message)
        status.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

        self.leftButton = Button(frame, text="<", command=self.leftTurn)
        self.leftButton.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

        self.rightButton = Button(frame, text=">", command=self.rightTurn)
        self.rightButton.grid(row = 1, column = 3)

        self.upButton = Button(frame, text="^", command=self.upTurn)
        self.upButton.grid(row = 0, column = 2)

        self.downButton = Button(frame, text="V", command=self.downTurn)
        self.downButton.grid(row=2, column = 2)

    def leftTurn(self):
        message = "Left"
        print message

    def rightTurn(self):
        message = "Right"
    print message

    def upTurn(self):
        message = "Up"
        print message

    def downTurn(self):
        message = "Down"
        print message



root = Tk()
root.geometry("640x480")
root.title("Rover ")

app = App(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you want is to bind the key press to the frame/function. Tkinter has its own event and binding handling built in which you can read up on [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm).

Here is quick example which you should be able to adapt your program.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def yourFunction(event):
    print('left')

frame = Frame(root, width=100, height=100)

frame.bind("<Left>",yourFunction)   #Binds the "left" key to the frame and exexutes yourFunction if "left" key was pressed
frame.pack()

root.mainloop()
```