# Python - Press key for press button on tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I use Tkinter and have a window with 3 buttons and need to do that when a keypad key is pressed is pressed one of the 3 buttons on the window (Do the same with 3 different keys).
These buttons work perfectly if I do click with the mouse, but want to do this by pressing keys

I have no idea how to do this, I hope you can help me. thanks

Answer (score 3):

The technical term you are missing is "bind".

You'll find plenty of information on [this previously answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20832909/how-to-bind-a-keypress-to-a-button-in-tkinter).

Edit: Took way too long to post this, didn't notice the comment above. BTW, is there a way to enable notifications for such things ? I guess comments are better suited for this kind of answer, but being a newcomer, I can't post them on anything but my own answers yet.

Comment: Don't worry, you seem like you have your head on straight. I suspect it won't be very long before you get comment privileges. It just takes a couple of votes on a good question/answer.